# Find the range of a set of numbers in c

Tags: c

```
#include "stdafx.h"

int main()
{
    int num, max = -32768, min = 32767, range;
    char choice = 'y';
    while (choice == 'y')
    {
        printf("\nenter any number ");
        scanf("%d", &num);
        if (num>max)
            max = num;
        if (num<min)
            min = num;
        range = max - min;
        printf("Range Is %d", range);
        printf("\nYou Want To Add Another Number(y/n) ");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%c", &choice);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

After one input, control exits from program even if the 'y' key is pressed.
I am trying to understand why does it exit my main loop

Comment: Don't `fflush(stdin);` is undefined behaviour, an alternative is `while ((c = fgetc(stdin)) != '\n' && c != EOF);`

Comment: Prefer `fgets()` (possibly followed by `sscanf()`) to deal with user input: it is better suited for error management than `scanf()`

Comment: @unwind It is a good starting point to set `min` to the biggest and `max` to the lowest possible value. The first value entered should clear that up. But instead of `-32768` and `32767`, it should read `INT_MIN` and `INT_MAX`.

Comment: Seems like `printf("Range Is %d", range);` will always print `0` for a value between -32768 and 32767.

Comment: @glglgl Doh. Right, of course. Thanks, brain error.

Comment: @glglgl Using `INT_MIN` and `INT_MAX` is a problem with `int range = max - min; printf("Range Is %d", range);`  OP seems to be relying on using an `int` subset to calculate `range`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code was that `scanf` kept the '\n' input.

You should start using `readline` instead of `scanf`, see [here](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html) for more info

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int     main()
{
  int           ret, num, max = -32768, min = 32767, range;
  char          *line = NULL;
  size_t        len = 0;
  ssize_t       read;
  char          choice = 'y';

  ret = 0;
  while (choice == 'y')
    {
      printf("\nenter any number ");
      if ((read = getline(&line, &len, stdin)) == -1)
        break ;
      num = atoi(line);
      if (num > max)
        max = num;
      if (num < min)
        min = num;
      range = max - min;
      printf("Range Is %d", range);
      printf("\nYou Want To Add Another Number(y/n) ");
      if ((read = getline(&line, &len, stdin)) == -1)
        break ;
      choice = line[0];
    }
  if (line) // line should be freed even if getline failed
    free(line);
  return 0;
}
```

So **How does it work ?** :

```
if ((read = getline(&line, &len, stdin)) == -1)
  break ; // break the while if getline failed
```

here `getline` take **3** parameters :

- a pointer to `line` where user input is stored
- a pointer to `len` where the size of `line` is stored in bytes
- `stdin` which is the File Stream (`FILE *`) of standard input

From `man 3 getline`

> ssize_t getline(char **lineptr, size_t *n, FILE *stream);
>
> `getline()` reads an entire line from stream, storing the address of the
>   buffer containing the text into `*lineptr`.  The buffer is
>   null-terminated and includes the newline character, if one was found.
>
> If `*lineptr` is set to **NULL** and `*n` is set 0 before the call, then `getline()` will allocate a buffer for storing the line.  This
>   buffer should be freed by the user program even if `getline()` failed.

Comment: Note that `getline()` is not presently part of the C standard library.

Answer (score 0):

First the solution of your problemo. It's simple replace `"%c"` by `" %c"`. Yeah give a space before C. And I too wrote a prog. if you'll like to see:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
int max, min, holder, no_of_inputs, tally;
char consent;
int array[2];
printf("TOTAL NUMBER OF INPUTS ANTICIPATED: ");
scanf("%d", &no_of_inputs);
printf("INPUT 1:  ");
scanf("%d", &array[0]);
printf("INPUT 2:  ");
scanf("%d", &array[1]);
if (array[0] > array[1])
    max = array[0], min = array[1];
else
    max = array[1], min = array[0];
for (tally = 3; tally <= no_of_inputs; ++tally)
{

    printf("INPUT %d:  ", tally);
    scanf("%d", &holder);
    if (holder > max)
        max = holder;
    else
        min = holder;
}
printf("RANGE: %d.", max - min);
return 0;
}.
```

If you really wanna go yes/no way here it is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
int max, min, holder, no_of_inputs;
char consent;
int array[2];
printf("INPUT:  ");
scanf("%d", &array[0]);
printf("INPUT:  ");
scanf("%d", &array[1]);
if (array[0] > array[1])
{
    max = array[0], min = array[1];
}
else
{
    max = array[1], min = array[0];
};
while (1 > 0)
{
    printf("WANNA GIVE MORE INPUT(y/n): ");
    scanf(" %c", &consent); //notice the space.
    if (consent == 'n')
    {
        break;
    }

    else if (consent == 'y')
    {
        printf("INPUT:  ");
        scanf("%d", &holder);
        if (holder > max)
        {
            max = holder;
        }
        else if (holder < min)
        {
            min = holder;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("ERROR!!\n");
        break;
    };
}
printf("RANGE: %d", max - min);
return 0;
}
```

THANKS.